# In .NET, System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal isn't updating

Tags: .net, multithreading, current-principal

I'm missing something elementary here when debugging some .NET code:

```
    public static void CreateServiceSessionStore()
    {
        ServiceSessionStore serviceSessionStore = new ServiceSessionStore();
        serviceSessionStore.SetIdentity(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity);
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = serviceSessionStore;
        // Here, CurrentPrincipal still isn't a serviceSessionStore!
    }
```

In this code, everything seems to chug merrily along.  However...when I debug and am just before the last line, I'm looking at System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.  The value is a WebSessionStore object, which is what I expect, and what I am thinking the last line should change it to a ServiceSessionStore object.  But it doesn't.  I can look at serviceSessionStore, and it's holding a ServiceSessionStore object, but after the line runs CurrentPrincipal still contains a WebSessionStore object.  No error is thrown.

Now, aside from what these objects actually do, can someone offer an idea about why it seems to be refusing to update CurrentPrincipal?

Comment: I strongly suspect lack of permission (SecurityPermission). I've got no clue why you'd _not_ see the exception thrown however. Interesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a debugger artifact.  Debug expressions are evaluated on a dedicated debugger thread.  CurrentPrincipal is a property of the thread's execution context. Also the reason it can be a static property.  Different threads will have different principals and the debugger thread's principal is therefore not the same.

You don't have a real problem.

Comment: Facinating theory.  And seems to be true, as an added bonus.  Cha-ching!